# convert string to float in js

Tags: javascript, html, django

i am googling for an half hour and found some famous solutions, but they are not working for me somehow.

```
var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
//alert(latitude + ' - ' + longitude);
$('#lat').val(parseFloat(latitude));
$('#long').val(parseFloat(longitude));
```

above is my code. i am still becoming error, `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '48.2767085'` in django which is `lat` value. why is this? i am converting string to float and then setting the value, why it is still thinking that this is a string?

thanks for any help

Comment: If you're getting an error in your Python code, you should post that rather than this Javascript.

Comment: yeah, i think this question is too dumb, i should set rather in serverside and see what happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that it's a string, the problem is that the string *does not contain a valid int*.

```
>>> int('4.2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4.2'
>>> int('4')
4
>>> float('4.2')
4.2
```

Comment: oh yeah, i will change model field to float, then it should work. now i have BigIntegerField.

Comment: it worked - i changed BigInteger to FloatField. now working like a charm :), thanks dude